# how to filter model with a list containing the field and the value?

Tags: python, django

see what I have:

```
> bar = [(u'code__regex', u'^[^J]'), (u'active__exact', u'0'), (u'type__id__exact', u'E01')]
```

There are the fields/values that I want to use to filter the model Foo.

```
> #want to have this equivalent:
> Foo.objects.filter(bar)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Foo.objects.filter(**dict(bar))
```

This isn't a django issue, this is a python issue.  You want to pass the keyword pairs as keyword arguments (kwargs) to the filter.  Your `bar` is *perfect* as a kwarg set, so the `dict(bar)` converts it to the dictionary, and the `**` prefix informs the python parser that the dictionary is to be interpreted as keyword arguments by the receiver.

Stack overflow entry [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) covers this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks! it raises a TypeError: filter() keywords must be strings. Because the args comes in unicode, if we convert them to strings this works nice!.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say if you want it in AND or OR. If AND is ok then you can simply convert that list into a dictionary and pass it to filter:

```
Foo.objects.filter(**dict(bar))
```

Comment: OR is trickier: `Foo.objects.filter(reduce(operator.__or__, [Q(**dict([i])) for i in bar]))` is the shortest way I know to achieve this.  You have to import both django.db.models.Q and operator.